# Maven- Unable to unpack specific tar resources

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I am using maven dependency plugin to unpack an internal tar file. I run the command with `mvn generate-resources` however it unpacks every resources and all i really care about is my own. I haven't used maven much but is there a way just to unpack my one resource so that I save execution time

My plugin is configured as such

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>build-tools</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <includeTypes>tar.gz</includeTypes>
                                <type>tar.gz</type>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                                <includeArtifactIds>build-tools</includeArtifactIds>
                                <includeGroupIds>com.foo.build</includeGroupIds>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: I didn't see it at first, but now it is obvious: the configuration elements should not be inside `<artifactItems>`, but outside of it. Remove `<artifactItems><artifactItem>`, and all will be well.

Comment: Awesome that was it. Why was that causing it?. Can you add it is an answer so I can give you credit for it? @Tunaki